# Prove the Inequality on Prime Counting Function

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Is there any way to prove that,

$$\pi(x^2)-\pi(y^2) \geq \sqrt{\pi(x-y)}$$

I have tried to prove it using inequalities on $\pi(x)$ but it didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: @Henry: Sorry, edited.

Comment: Must it be assumed that $x>y$?

Comment: @ajotatxe: Since in case $x=y$ there is no counterexample, you may assume that. To be precise $x \geq y$.

Answer (score 1):

When $x-y = 2$ this is a slight weakening of [Legendre's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture), which is suspected to hold but certainly isn't known to.

Comment: Actually my original problem was to show that there exists an $n$ such that $\pi(x^2)-\pi(y^2)\geq \sqrt[n]{\pi(x+y)}$ holds. Here I gave a stronger version.